# How to set accent color for Push icon in Android with react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I am using [react-native-marketingcloudsdk](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk) library in my React native project, For android to set the `default_notification_color` I have tried both `AndroidManifest.xml` & `firebase.json` ways, but still when I receive push notification from `SFMC` It's showing only the Blue colour, If I receive push notification from `fcm API` the colour which I have applied is reflecting.

```
---AndroidManifest.xml
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/accentColor"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />

---firebase.json
{
  "react-native": {
    "android_task_executor_maximum_pool_size": 10,
    "android_task_executor_keep_alive_seconds": 3,
    "messaging_android_notification_color": "@color/accentColor"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize notifications. See the documentation: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Bill Mote, I have set the notification color by adding below code in `MainApplication.java` `MarketingCloudSdk.init()`

```
.setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                        NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(new NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder() {
                            @NonNull @Override
                            public NotificationCompat.Builder setupNotificationBuilder(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
                                NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                                    NotificationManager.getDefaultNotificationBuilder(
                                        context,
                                        notificationMessage,
                                        NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context),
                                        R.drawable.ic_notification
                                    );
                                //Set Notification Icon Color
                                builder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor));

                                builder.setContentIntent(
                                    NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(
                                        context,
                                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                            context,
                                            new Random().nextInt(),
                                            context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName()),
                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
                                        ),
                                        notificationMessage,
                                        true
                                    )
                                );
                                return builder;
                            }
                        })
                    )
```